# Nginx ssl handshake failure , Unknown SSL protocol error

Tags: apache, ssl, nginx

I have nginx installed on Debian

```
nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.2.1
TLS SNI support enabled
```

when I do

```
 curl -1 -v "https:<my domain>"
```

I get

```
 * About to connect() to <my domain> port 443 (#0)
 *   Trying <my ip>... connected
 * Connected to <my domain> (<my ip>) port 443 (#0)
 * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
 * Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to <my domain>:443 
 * Closing connection #0
 curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to <my domain>:443
```

my nginx is acting as proxy to apache and nginx vhost configuraion is as follows

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  <my domain>;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/wildcard.<my domain>-chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/private/wildcard.<my domain>.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://<my ip>:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Please advice what is wrong here. I can access the url from the browser with valid certificate.

Comment: Look at the server (nginx) side error messages in the log file.

Comment: There is nothing in the log file for this request. Neither in Nginx nor in apache

Comment: Same setup works on a Ubuntu machine with 

nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

Now it seems I will have to upgrade my nginx but what I have is the highest version provided by the repository. Searching for a safer way to do that

Comment: Given that you are using a 4 year old version of nginx my guess is that your OpenSSL is similar old and that you don't have the support for TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 you are trying to configure.

Comment: Nginx upgrade did not made any difference. However now I have stopped nginx and configured everything on apache and it works.
Any clue how I can make it work with Nginx on Debian